# How to show datagrid in ms access forms

Tags: ms-access

I have to create a ms access form which has a text box and a button. I want to retrieve multiple records from db and show all those rows in ms access Form on click of the button.is there a way to show multiple records on a ms access form something like a datagrid and once i retrieve those records I should be able to update them.Please let me know if there is a solution

Regards,
Ravi

Comment: Have you tried any Access tutorials at all? If you haven't, I recommend it. Had you already done so, you would likely have encountered continuous forms already.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are referring to a continuous form. Here are a few links on the subject.

http://www.blueclaw-db.com/access_continuous_form_subform.htm

http://www.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0024.htm

It is one of the main plus points of access and one which can be used to great affect. Failing that you can use the datagrid activeX control and populate it through code but that is a little more involved (still quite easy still)

Comment: Trouble is any external control then has distribution issues which require admin privileges.  I'd stay with continuous forms unless I had very, very good reasons.  Other than just jazzing up a GUI.  <smile>

Comment: Very good point about external controls, having said that if you stick to the windows common controls you (should) be fine. I cant remember if the datagrid is part of that. And of course jazzing up the UI is always a good use of time just look at how everyone loves 100% flash websites……..

Comment: How does an external datagrid "jazz up the UI?"

Comment: Well maybe “jazzing up” is a bit of a strong phrase, it does however bring a few more display options to the table. Personally I use a lot of the listview control to allow me to do things like highlight rows and do conditional formatting etc and of course its unbound but we wont start that debate up again!

Comment: I just think introducing an outside dependency is a bad idea. I'm very conservative on that after years of too many problems with it.

Comment: That’s a fair point, I guess it all depends on how controlled the environment you are developing is and how common the external control is you are using. At the moment I have the luxury of having a quite controlled i.e. standard build here so I know that they will all have MS common controls and so I can use it.

Comment: Keep in mind that you could have those invalidated by Microsoft Update, as recently happened to a lot of widely-used non-Access ActiveX controls with MS's killbit updates.